# How set cron job - PHP in digital ocean for daily bases?

Tags: php, cron, digital-ocean

I have set cron job command on my digital ocean server.
0 1 * * * php /var/www/html/domain/cron/index.php
is it right coded??
Because its not running daily.
Had check of 5mint and hourly, its working fine but not for each day.
Please help me to find out the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your cron commands are OK by typing:

```
$ crontab -l
```

or right in

```
/var/spool/cron/crontab
```

Your command seems to be OK for a script that will be executed every day at 01AM.

Comment: i had write code in /etc/crontab file...is it correct file?

Comment: Use "crontab -e" command, instead. The crontab in VPS are proper for every user.

Comment: If you want to use /etc/crontab should use the user name also, in this situation "root": 0 1 * * * root php /var/www/...

Answer (score 2):

`0 1 * * *` means your php file will execute on 01:00:00, and this depend on your where your server is located (server's time zone).

[Check this site.](http://crontab.guru/#0_1_*_*_*) it will help you to set time for your cron job.

and if your cron is running for 5 minute, it should work for daily basis, you have to just figure out at what time it should run.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your droplet and then follow this steps

```
crontab -e
* * * * * cd project_path/ && php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Example:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/blog/ && php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: But i am not using laravel.